# Cannot cradle after connecting to emulator on Win 10

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-embedded

I want to connect a `Windows Mobile 6.5 Emulator` with the `Windows Mobile Device Manager`. After I start the `Device Emulator Manager` as stand alone, I select a emulator and right click it and connect to the emulator. The Emulator will start as expected and everything is fine. So far... Usually I can cradle with right clicking on the emulator in the `Device Emulator Manager`, but after doing so, every possible option is displayed grey and is not clickable.

The mouse cursor is a spinning circle. This spinning circle will be there for ever and there is also no green array appearing, that I am connected the the emulator. The emulator meanwhile is loaded completely and I am able to interact with it. After closing the emulator, I get the error message

> Cannot connect to device. Error: 0x89731c01

**What I did so far:**

- Changed the connection settings in the `Windows Mobile Device Manager` to `DMA`
- Made sure the needed windows services are running and I use my Windows Authentification for the services
- Reinstalling the whole thing several times including restarts of Windows
- Turning of the Windows Firewall

**My Setup**

- Windows 10 V1703 64bit
- Installed Microsoft Windows Mobile Device Center 6.1 Driver (64-bit)
- Installed Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK Refresh
- Installed Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional Developer Tool Kit (USA)
- Installed Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional Images (GER)
- Visual Studio 2008 Professional
- .NET Compact Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2 Redistributable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by installing SP1 for VS2008 and run the `Device Emulator Manager` in `Compatibility Mode` to `Windows XP SP3`. I still don´t know why, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware of, the Windows 10 Creators Update blocks WMDC to connect and work with Windows Mobile / CE devices and Emulator. There are various sites describing this issue with some workarounds, ie http://www.junipersys.com/Juniper-Systems-Rugged-Handheld-Computers/support/Knowledge-Base/Support-Knowledge-Base-Topics/Desktop-Connection-ActiveSync-or-Windows-Mobile-Device-Center/WMDC-in-Windows-10, https://community.trimble.com/docs/DOC-13304-windows-mobile-device-center-wont-run-on-latest-windows-10-os, https://www.handheldgroup.com/support-rugged-computers/knowledgebase-KB/22996/, https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/evm/windows-ce-device-does-not-connect-with-windows-10-with-creators-upgrade-via-wmdc.html, ...